# PUT Stream 0 Bytes

Tags: file-upload, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am using Windows Explorer to test the WebDAV implementation I am adapting to our system. The implementation is using IIS Express and is launched by Visual Studio 2013. I turned off Windows Explorer's requirement for SSL with WebDAV so I can test basic authentication (which works).

The problem I am having is with the Write method of the DavFile implementation. I connect to the web folder, navigate to a sub folder, then attempt to copy a JPG file from a folder on my computer's hard drive, into the WebDAV sub folder (using Windows Explorer).

The attempt to copy up a file (854kb) fails. When I set a break point, I notice that the "segment" stream (one of the input parameters on the "write" method, shows 0 (zero) bytes length.

Any tips on how to debug this problem? What is the most likely cause of 0 byte in the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas about how to understand what is going wrong:

1. Examine the server log for exceptions. By default it is called WebDAVLog.txt and located in \App_Data\WebDAV\Logs\ folder. Are there any exceptions in it? Check your server log and make sure all requests were successful.
2. Examine WebDAV requests with a Fiddler tool or any other debugging proxy. While all requests that reached the WebDAV server Engine are logged, if the request failed before hitting the Engine you will not see it in a log. Usually this happens if the request failed during authentication stage.

   Note that to capture requests using Fiddler on 'localhost' you must use 'localhost.fiddler' instead of 'localhost' when connecting to server, for example: http://localhost.fiddler:1234.
3. Exclude any client side issues. Finally there could be issues with client software that you are using, including with Microsoft miniredirector. Try to access server from any other machine. To get the idea if the problem is on the client or server side try also to reproduce the issue on ajaxbrowser.com.

You can post a part of the WebDAVLog.txt or fiddler log here or send it to IT Hit, it may give the idea of what is wrong.

Comment: I am currently working through the "Integration" tests, to make sure everything is OK. Then I'll run through 1 through 3 above.